# How do you execute maven's spring-boot:run when you have jdk 1.8 code?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am effectively asking this question, but for the `spring-boot:run` goal: [how to pass --add-opens JDK module configuration to maven test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64920521/how-to-pass-add-opens-jdk-module-configuration-to-maven-test)

For context, I'm trying to execute spring-boot 1.5.1.RELEASE code that was written for jdk1.8 in jdk16. JDK 9 introduced the concept of modules, and this was a backwards incompatible change, though from my research, it looks like there are workarounds. When I run the code, I get this error:

> Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module

Rather than add modules to this old project, I want to get past this with minimal modification to the existing project. What do I have to do to run my application without adding modules? one workaround I know would work is to download JDK 8 and run the code with that, but that doesn't seem like a good solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I found an answer, but I'd like to know if there's a better way:

```
<build>
    <finalName>project</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <jvmArguments>--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED</jvmArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Quite annoying having to repeat the list of add-opens there and in MANIFEST

Comment: IMHO you should also inject it in MANIFEST.MF in order to simplify the war/jar execution.