# Mockito Inaccessible Object exception while creating a mock object

Tags: java, mockito

Getting a `java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException` while trying to Mock an object

```
Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @238e0d81
```

Comment: I was facing similar issue with java 16, I switch to java 8, that resolved my issue. Also this is my mockito dependency <groupId>org.mockito</groupId><artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId><version>1.10.19</version>, check if this works for you

Comment: @AbhiK Same, switching from java 17 to java 15 fixed it for me.

Comment: This might be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74106907/2574965

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This can happen if Mockito requires reflective access to non-public parts in a Java module. If you want to stick with a newer Java version, you can get around this by explicitly allowing access via `--add-opens` in your `java` call - the error message is helpful in that it gives you both the required module and package:

`java --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED ...`

(Where the target `ALL-UNNAMED` applies to all non-modular classes. See, e.g., https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html for a brief introduction into these directives.)

Note that this option does not apply during compilation, i.e., *not* to `javac`; it is a runtime option.

If you are using Gradle, you can add this to the [test task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html) in your `build.gradle`:

```
    test {
         jvmArgs '--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED'
     }
```

Or, an alternative syntax to the same effect:

```
    test {
         jvmArgs '--add-opens', 'java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED'
     }
```

Comment: I have maven, what should i do

Comment: I am not familiar with Maven, but this sounds related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64920521/how-to-pass-add-opens-jdk-module-configuration-to-maven-test

Comment: This also applies to running tests with Mockito in the Intellij IDE. I had to add that to the JUNIT template.

Comment: Example on how to add multiples:
`jvmArgs '--add-opens', 'java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED', '--add-opens', 'java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED', '--add-opens', 'java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED'`