# Maven compiler plugin error compiling, while executing mvn package or mvn clean install

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I cloned a project from `github`, the projects made using `java 8`, `spring boot`, `mysql`,

so the first thing I did was configuring the jdk in `intellij`, I have `openjdk 17` , and `15` , so I chose `v15` , I run the application,

it's running fine, and when I tried to make `mvn package` this error came out:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project platform: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor (in unnamed module @0x16a9eb2e) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module @0x16a9eb2e
```

---

## This is the `pom.xml` file:

````
type h<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ezlearning</groupId>
    <artifactId>platform</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>platform</name>
    <description>Ez learning platform</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Thymeleaf Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MySql dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Database versioning -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Boot Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```
````

---

## `Screenshots`

---

1. [image]

---

2. [image]

---

3. [image]

---

I tried to check the `Maven` version in my machine , and it's `3.8.5`, so I don't know if the problem is because the project's `Maven` compiler is `3.8.1` and mine is `3.8.5`, I'm a newbie so I really dont have a solution for this , I'm just trying to containerize this application  that's why I'm building the `jar` file.

Comment: As you probably want to compile for Java 8 instead of 15 or 17, you could try to add `<maven.compiler.source>`, `<maven.compiler.target>` as well as `<maven.compiler.release>` properties for Java 8. If this still does not work you need to open the respective modules to the unnamed module. This can either be done by adding that option to the respective plugin, i.e. [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64920521/how-to-pass-add-opens-jdk-module-configuration-to-maven-test) or via a [.mvn/jvm.config file](https://nipafx.dev/maven-on-java-9/#applying-java-9-flags-to-maven-process)

Comment: If this project used lombok you have to correctly configure lombok ... there is a documentation how to do that correctly... also your spring boot version is out of date...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your pom.xml , properties, add these:

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <!-- START ADD 20230219 -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <!-- END ADD 20230219 -->
    </properties>
```

in dependency org.projectlombok , add version

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

I already test OK, in command line or in IDEA IDE.

---

Other answer maybe can OK in command line , but fail in IDEA IDE.

like this:  can OK in command line , but fail in IDEA IDE.

I am test, not good answer in IDEA IDE.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <fork>true</fork>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>--enable-preview</arg>
            <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
            <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
            <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
            <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
            <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
            <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
            <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
            <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
            <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
            <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
            <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
        <!--for unmappable characters in classes-->
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.20</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```